# Django:: Cant update form

Tags: python, html, django

I have gone blind trying to figure this out...

I have done everything correctly but for some reason I am unable to update a form.

url.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('Auditor/', views.Auditor, name='Auditor'),
    path('Auditor/<str:pk>/', views.auditFormPage, name='AuditForm'),
    path('register/', views.registerPage, name='Register'),
    path('Login/', views.loginPage, name='Login'),
    

]

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

views.py

```
def Auditor(request):
    model = datas.objects.filter(qs_login='nicobari')
    context = {'items': model }
    return render(request,"main/auditform.html",context)


def auditFormPage(request, pk):
    model = datas.objects.filter(qs_login='nicobari')
    data= datas.objects.get(Task_ID=pk)
    
    form = auditForm(instance=data)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = auditForm(request.POST, instance=data)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()

    context = {
    "items": model,
    "data": data
    }   

    return render(request,"main/auditform.html", context)
```

form.py:

```
class auditForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = datas
        fields = '__all__'
```

Everything works but when i try to click on :

```
<input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
```

It just refreshes the page but doesnt update the content.

Could anyone help me understand what I could have done wrong?

Models.py

```
class datas(models.Model):

    country = models.CharField(_('country'),max_length=200,default='Null') 
    qs_login = models.CharField(_('qs_login'),max_length=200,default='Null') 
    Status = models.CharField(_('Status'),max_length=200,default='Null') 
    seller_id = models.CharField(_('seller_id'),max_length=200,default='Null') 
    Task_ID = models.CharField(_('Task_ID'),max_length=200,default='Null',primary_key=True) 
    associate_queue = models.CharField(_('associate_queue'),max_length=200,default='Null') 
    associate = models.CharField(_('associate'),max_length=200,default='Null') 
    metric_wk_no = models.CharField(_('associate'),max_length=200,default='Null') 
    associate_action = models.CharField(_('associate_action'),max_length=200,default='Null') 
    correct_associate_action = models.CharField(_('correct associate action'),max_length=200,default='Null') 
    Associate_Key_Driver = models.CharField(_('Associate_Key_Driver'),max_length=200,default='Null') 
    Sub_Key_driver = models.CharField(_('country'),max_length=200,default='Null') 
    Defect_Area_Associate = models.CharField(_('Defect Area Associate'),max_length=200,default='Null') 
    QA_Comments_on_Associate_Action = models.CharField(_('country'),max_length=400,default='Null') 
    Metric_name = models.CharField(_('Metric name'),max_length=200,default='Null') 


    #SIV
    investigator_task = models.CharField(_('investigator_task'),max_length=200,default='Null') 
    investigator_queue = models.CharField(_('investigator_queue'),max_length=200,default='Null') 
    investigator = models.CharField(_('investigator'),max_length=200,default='Null') 
    verification_action = models.CharField(_('verification_action'),max_length=200,default='Null') 
    correct_investigator_action = models.CharField(_('correct investigator action'),max_length=200,default='Null') 
    Investigator_Key_Driver = models.CharField(_('Investigator Key-Driver'),max_length=200,default='Null') 
    Defect_Area_Investigator = models.CharField(_('Defect Area Investigator'),max_length=200,default='Null') 
    QA_Comments_on_investigator_Action = models.CharField(_('QA Comments on investigator Action'),max_length=200,default='Null') 
    General_Notes = models.CharField(_('General_Notes'),max_length=200,default='Null') 
    
    Action_correctly_captured = models.CharField(_('Action_correctly_captured'),max_length=200,default='Null') 
    Audit_outcome = models.CharField(_('Audit_outcome'),max_length=200,default='Null') 
    associate_resolve_date = models.CharField(_('associate_resolve_date'),max_length=200,default='Null') 
    Type_of_audit = models.CharField(_('Type_of_audit'),max_length=200,default='Null') 
    If_data_correctly_captured= models.CharField(_('If_data_correctly_captured'),max_length=200,default='Null') 

    def __str__(self):
        return f"File: {self.country}-{self.qs_login}-{self.Status}-{self.seller_id}-{self.Task_ID}-{self.associate_queue}-{self.associate}-{self.metric_wk_no}-{self.associate_action}-{self.correct_associate_action}-{self.Associate_Key_Driver}-{self.Sub_Key_driver}-{self.Defect_Area_Associate}-{self.QA_Comments_on_Associate_Action}-{self.Metric_name}-{self.investigator_task}-{self.investigator_queue}-{self.investigator}-{self.verification_action}-{self.correct_investigator_action}-{self.Investigator_Key_Driver}-{self.Defect_Area_Investigator}-{self.QA_Comments_on_investigator_Action}-{self.General_Notes}-{self.Type_of_audit}-{self.Action_correctly_captured}-{self.Audit_outcome}-{self.associate_resolve_date}-{self.If_data_correctly_captured}"
```

Comment: We need more detail.  To start with, show us `urls.py` and `main/auditform.html`.

Comment: Done! added the main chuck of html as I cant fit it all in there

Comment: The `Mainpage` and `updateform` views aren't listed in urls.py.  How are they called?

Comment: Updated that too, sorry I had changed the names initially so it was easier to understand, thanks for helping me with this, I owe you big time,,<3

Comment: I am able to update the page with the data on the model, but i cant seem to save any changes to the form. Ive attached screeshots of how the page looks

Comment: Sooooo, ive noticed someething, when i look at my CMD , it says the following: main.models.datas.DoesNotExist: datas matching query does not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
def auditFormPage(request, pk):
    model = datas.objects.filter(qs_login='nicobari')
    data= datas.objects.get(Task_ID=pk)
    
    form = auditForm(instance=data)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = auditForm(request.POST, instance=data)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    else:
        form = auditForm(instance=data)
        context = {
        "items": model,
        "data": data
        }   
    return render(request,"main/auditform.html", context)
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that the form is valid (please check if it is) and you got to the point where you saved `data`, you are still pointing to the old snapshot of `data` when you pass the context to the template. So if you refresh the page again, you should see the updated changes.

What you can do is if it's a POST request, get the new data that was updated before passing it back to render context:

```
def auditFormPage(request, pk):
    model = datas.objects.filter(qs_login='nicobari')
    data= datas.objects.get(Task_ID=pk)
    
    form = auditForm(instance=data)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = auditForm(request.POST, instance=data)
        if form.is_valid():
            data = form.save() # <-- Add this to get the updated data instance

    context = {
        "items": model,
        "data": data,
    }   

    return render(request,"main/auditform.html", context)
```

Comment: Hello!!!! Thank you for taking your time with this,  So about my form I guess its correct because it populates  the fields with the current data in the model but i never got to the point where i saved data because that is where im stuck on.

Comment: Try to debug if it does reach the save. Put a breakpoint or print statements.

Comment: Ive tried that but it doesnt update the form still... its driving me mad!!! but i think what you are trying to do is in the right thing. i tried to put an else statement, to show a message box to atleast show that it didnt save but even that message box isnt showing...which is strange.

Comment: Thankssss, it is so strange, because i tried to do this in the past but the debugging thing when using django but never worked. let me google that now a second

Comment: How do you show thr message box? Maybe try just printing which would be simpler

Comment: Sooooo i noticed something in the CMD line that i get the following warning:   raise self.model.DoesNotExist(
main.models.datas.DoesNotExist: datas matching query does not exist.

Comment: This is strange because the model does exhist infact it populates the page with this data.... i updated the main question with my models.py and forms.py

Comment: Thank you soo much for helping me with this.... im just soo lost right now..

Comment: Can you show the whole traceback? Hard to guess without any info

Comment: Also in your form, make sure that action is set to the same view/url. So `form method='POST' action=<your view's url>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235480/discussion-between-king-and-bdbd).